# Most used columns in each tables in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to find out (Query) which are the most used Columns in a tables. In other words, looking for a way to find out the columns in a table that are most frequently accessed?

Comment: When you say "*most frequently accessed*" do you mean *the columns that are referenced by the most number of database objects* or do you mean *the columns that are read from the most when queried*?

Answer (score 1):

If your data access is exclusively modules (Stored Procedures, Functions, etc.), you can get a rough idea by querying [sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referencing-entities-transact-sql) - this will get you a list of objects that reference your table.

Then you can combine it with the [sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql) - this, in turn, gives you which columns are referenced by the referencing entities.

If you put it together

```
DECLARE @schema sysname = 'Sales'
DECLARE @object sysname = 'Customers'

SELECT 
    refed.referenced_minor_name
    , COUNT(1) AS refCount
    , STRING_AGG(CONCAT(refing.referencing_schema_name,'.', refing.referencing_entity_name), ' | ') AS refingAggregate
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(CONCAT(@schema,'.',@object) , 'object') AS refing
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(CONCAT(refing.referencing_schema_name, '.', refing.referencing_entity_name), 'object') AS refed
WHERE 
    refed.referenced_schema_name = @schema
    AND refed.referenced_entity_name = @object
    AND refed.referenced_minor_name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY refed.referenced_minor_name
ORDER BY refCount DESC
```

Please note that this detects only non-encrypted modules in your database. An ORM or another type of access will not be shown here.

[image]

A more complex option would be to run a custom ScriptDOM script against your code base.

This will give you only the number of references, though.

To find the access numbers, you need to collect actual execution counts (for example, with Extended Events `module_start`).

Comment: While this is a good answer (and admittedly helpful for me to know actually), I'm not sure this actually answer's OP's question "*...the columns in a table that are most frequently accessed?*". I understood his question the same way as Erik did, but I'm asking OP to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Flat out, no. You can only get some (usually not great) information about which indexes are read from and modified the most. But that still won't tell you which columns in those indexes are read/modified, unless there's only one column in the index.